# Multiple Text Inputs Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I have been trying to figure out how to have multiple inputs connect with one output object in Shiny.

I have a table as an output, and I want to show only specific rows of that table depending on what the user enters in a text box. In my example, the table has columns: Name, Address, DateOfBirth, ID, Next Appointment.

I filter the user's input based on regular expressions, which works great, but it breaks down when trying to differentiate between DateOfBirth and NextAppointment, since they are both YYYY-MM-DD.

How can I create a new text input that will not interfere with the first? I cannot get this to work. Do I need to use something other than the submit button?

My program right now will only search based on the first text input box. The second text input box is not active. This is where I need your help.

Thanks very much in advance. Here is my sample app code:

```
library(shiny)

#ui.R
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
ui = shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test App"),
  sidebarPanel(
    #declare 2 text inputs and submit button
    textInput(inputId = "variableInput", label = "Search by Name, ID or Date of Birth"),
    textInput(inputId = "NextAppt", "Search by Next Appointment"),
    submitButton(text = "Submit")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    #declare text output(s)
    #I don't want to have 2 table outputs
    #ideally I would have 2 search boxes for 1 table
    tableOutput("Variable")
    #,tableOutput("NextAppt")   
  )
))


#server.R
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
server = shinyServer(function(input, output){
  #make sample table with values. each vector represents a column
  Name = c("Person1", "Person2", "Person3")
  Address = c("101 E St", "102 E St", "103 E St")
  DateOfBirth = c("1990-01-01", "1990-01-02", "1990-01-03")
  ID = c("12345", "23456", "34567")
  NextAppointment = c("2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16")
  df = data.frame(Name, Address, DateOfBirth, ID, NextAppointment)

  #determine what the user is searching for by using regular expressions
  #if the user entered something like ####-##-##, where # is any number,
  #then they must have entered a date
  #if the user enters #####, then it must be an ID
  #otherwise, they entered a name
  #search.criteria() is a vector of the rows of our dataframe to display
  search.criteria <- reactive({
    if(grepl("\\d{4}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}", input$variableInput)==TRUE){
      which(df$DateOfBirth==input$variableInput)
    } else if(grepl("\\d{5}", input$variableInput)==TRUE){
      which(df$ID==input$variableInput)
    } else{
      which(df$Name==input$variableInput)
    }
  })

  #create output table
  output$Variable = renderTable({
    df[search.criteria(), ]    #use the search.critera() reactive to determine rows to display
  })

})


#app.R
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: If DateOfBirth and NextAppointment do not overlap, you could add a rule to select which field to filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```
 library(shiny)

#ui.R
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
ui = shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test App"),
  sidebarPanel(
    #declare 2 text inputs and submit button
    textInput(inputId = "variableInput", label = "Search by Name, ID, Date of Birth"),
    textInput(inputId = "NextAppt", label = "Next Appointment"),
    submitButton(text = "Submit")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    #declare text output(s)
    #I don't want to have 2 table outputs
    #ideally I would have 2 search boxes for 1 table
    tableOutput("Variable")
    #,tableOutput("NextAppt")   
  )
))


#server.R
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
server = shinyServer(function(input, output){
  #make sample table with values. each vector represents a column
  Name = c("Person1", "Person2", "Person3")
  Address = c("101 E St", "102 E St", "103 E St")
  DateOfBirth = c("1990-01-01", "1990-01-02", "1990-01-03")
  ID = c("12345", "23456", "34567")
  NextAppointment = c("2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16")
  df = data.frame(Name, Address, DateOfBirth, ID, NextAppointment)

  #determine what the user is searching for by using regular expressions
  #if the user entered something like ####-##-##, where # is any number,
  #then they must have entered a date
  #if the user enters #####, then it must be an ID
  #otherwise, they entered a name
  #search.criteria() is a vector of the rows of our dataframe to display
  search.criteria <- reactive({
    out <- c()
    outAppt <- c()
    if(grepl("\\d{4}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}", input$variableInput)==TRUE){
      out <- which(df$DateOfBirth==input$variableInput)
      print(out)
    } else if(grepl("\\d{5}", input$variableInput)==TRUE){
      out <- which(df$ID==input$variableInput)
    } else{
      out <- which(df$Name==input$variableInput)
    }
    # filter for appointment
    if(grepl("\\d{4}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}", input$NextAppt)==TRUE){
      outAppt <- which(df$NextAppointment==input$NextAppt)
      if(length(out)){
        out <- intersect(out, outAppt)
      }else{
        out <- outAppt
      }
    }
    out
  })

  #create output table
  output$Variable = renderTable({
    print(search.criteria())
    df[search.criteria(), ]    #use the search.critera() reactive to determine rows to display
  })

})


#app.R
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I see what you did, but it still seems that it's not quite working. For some reason, the search does not actually execute when I only type something into the "Next Appointment" search box. Nothing happens. Could this be because the submit button is only tied to the first input box? I am not sure. Thanks again in advance for your help.

Comment: There is no more  "Next Appointment" search box. in my version, I am not sure i understand the problem :/

Comment: You're right! That was my fault. This does work, combining everything into one search box. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would you happen to know how I could have it be two text inputs? That would be ideal...I don't want to group too many things into the first search box. Thanks again!

Comment: I made an edit. Also consider the comment of HubertL for further adaptions.

Comment: Thank you BigDataScientist! You have been very, very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. You can thank the posters by upvote and accept the answers ;)